# Python 2.7 : Write to file instantly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I realized that when I write into a file using python it wait until the end of my Python file to execute it:

```
outputFile = open("./outputFile.txt","a")
outputFile.write("First")
print "Now you have 10sec to see that outputFile.txt is still the same as before"
time.sleep(10)
outputFile.write("Second")
print "Now if you look at outputFile.txt you will see 'First' and 'Second'"
```

How am I suppose to make python write instantly to the output file?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use `flush()` or you can set the file object to be unbuffered.

Details on using that parameter for `open()` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

So you would change your open call to -

```
outputFile = open("./outputFile.txt", "a", 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option is the best for me because I don't want to write outputFile.flush() each time but both work.

Comment: Instead of leaving the file open during time intensive operations it might be worth considering the with statement which would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @nachshon "accomplish the same thing": not for me on my system (RHEL 6.8 with [conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager))-based Python 2.7.13). The `os.fsync()` call mentioned in [ffeast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41506739/257924)'s answer is required (can't say for sure for Microsoft Windows-based Python or other OS's).

Answer (score 29):

Force it with the `flush()` function, add

```
outputFile.flush()
```

at the end of your code.

Comment: If that code is added at the end of the Python file, nothing is accomplished that wouldn't have been anyway when the file is closed. Instead it should be executed possibly multiple times -- whenever it's desired to make sure all the output produced so far written to the file.

Answer (score 9):

Just to combine all of the above answers into a set of useful utility functions because a key requirement of the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707890/elbajo) (and myself!) is "[because I don't want to write outputFile.flush() each time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984092/python-2-7-write-to-file-instantly/41506739#comment28042389_18984187)":

```
import os
import tempfile
import time


def write_now(filep, msg):
    """Write msg to the file given by filep, forcing the msg to be written to the filesystem immediately (now).

    Without this, if you write to files, and then execute programs
    that should read them, the files will not show up in the program
    on disk.
    """
    filep.write(msg)
    filep.flush()
    # The above call to flush is not enough to write it to disk *now*;
    # according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41506739/257924 we must
    # also call fsync:
    os.fsync(filep)


def print_now(filep, msg):
    """Call write_now with msg plus a newline."""
    write_now(filep, msg + '\n')


# Example use with the with..as statement:
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='some_prefix_here.', suffix='.log', dir='.', delete=False) as logf:
    print_now(logf, "this is a test1")
    time.sleep(20)
    print_now(logf, "this is a test2")
```

Answer (score 8):

As @RyPeck said you can use `flush()` or set the file object to be 
unbuffered. 
But note the following (from 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file%20flush#file.flush):

> Flush the internal buffer, like stdio‘s fflush().
>
> Note flush() does not necessarily write the file’s data to disk. Use flush() followed by os.fsync() to ensure this behavior.

And a quote from `man 3 fflush`:

> Note that fflush() only flushes the user-space buffers provided by the C library.  To ensure that the data is physically stored on disk the kernel buffers must be  flushed  too,  for  example,
>          with sync(2) or fsync(2).

Comment: @Nam `os.fsync()` works perfectly on my system (RHEL 6.8 with [conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager))-based Python 2.7.13). Are you sure you don't have filesystem problems or an overloaded system?

Comment: I have no idea. I am on Ubuntu Desktop 16 and Python 2.7

Comment: I'd add that physical flushing to disk shouldn't really be necessary. It only makes a difference if you're about to unplug your HDD (in which case you should of course properly _unmount_ it!) or expecting an imminent system crash. If the purpose is just to allow other programs to read the file in real time, it's perfectly sufficient to have the data in the kernel buffers.