# Python: Is there a way to get the average of the n newest numbers in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to build a sort of a battery meter, where I have one program that collects voltage samples and adds it to an array. My idea is, that I collect a lot of data when the battery is full, and then build a function that will compare this data with the average of the last 100 or so readings of the voltage as new readings are added every few seconds as long as I don't interrupt the process.

I am using matplotlib to show the voltage output and so far it is working fine: [I posted an answer here on live changing graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457040/python-live-graph-update-from-a-changing-text-file/57075813#57075813)

The voltage function looks like this:

```
pullData = open("dynamicgraph.txt","r").read() //values are stored here in another function
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []

    averagevoltage = 0
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine)>=19:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            xar.append(np.int64(x)) //a datetime value
            yar.append(float(y))    //the reading 
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,yar)
    ax1.set_ylim(ymin=25,ymax=29)
    if len(yar) > 1:
        plt.title("Voltage: " + str(yar [-1]) + " Average voltage: "+ str(np.mean(yar)))
```

I am just wondering what the syntax of getting the average of the last x numbers of the array should look like?

```
if len(yar) > 100
    #get average of last 100 values only
```

Comment: numpy.average ? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.average.html#numpy.average

Comment: you can take the last 100 items of an array by doing `yar[-100:]`. You can then get the mean of this by doing `np.mean(yar[-100:])`.

Comment: Oh it was really so easy, I even had that annotation `str(yar [-1])` there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rather simple problem. Assuming you're using numpy which provides easy functions for averaging.

```
array = np.random.rand(200, 1)

last100 = array[-100:]  # Retrieve last 100 entries
print(np.average(last100))  # Get the average of them
```

If you want to cast your normal array to a numpy array you can do it with:

```
np.array(<your-array-goes-here>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use slice notation with negative index to get the n last items in a list.

```
yar[-100:]
```

If the slice is larger than the list, the entire list will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need to use numpy. You can access the last 100 elements by slicing your array as follows:

```
l = yar[-100:]
```

This returns all elements at indices from -100 ('100th' last element) to -1 (last element). Then, you can just native Python functions as follows.

```
mean = sum(l) / len(l)
```

Sum(x) returns the sum of all values within the list, and len(l) returns the length of the list.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Python Standard Library [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html):

```
import statistics

statistics.mean(your_data_list[-n:])  # n = n newst numbers
```