# redirect python screen output in a file instantly under bash

Tags: python, bash

once i run a python script under bash by

```
python a.py >> output.txt
```

it is found that the screen output is not written to output.txt instantly. is there any way to ensure that output.txt could always up-to-date as we see it on the screen without redirection?
  some reference: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984092/python-2-7-write-to-file-instantly) has helped python write to file instantly. i am wondering if we can do the same thing for screen output as well.