# cannot print the data from external file in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to print the data from external file(test.txt) after truncating it in python 3.6

But, when I try to do that with open() and read() after writing it with the write(), it is not working.

```
from sys import argv
script,filename=argv
print(f"We're going to erase {filename}.")
print("If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).")
print("If you do want that, hit RETURN.")
input("?")

print("Opening the file...")
target=open(filename,"w")

print("Truncating the file. Goodbye!")
target.truncate()

print("Now I'm going to ask you for the three lines.")
line1=input("line 1: ")
line2=input("line 2: ")
line3=input("line 3: ")

print("I'm going to write these to the file")
target.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3 + "\n")
a=input("Please type the filename once again:")
b=open(a)
c=b.read()
print(c)
print("And finally, we close it.")
target.close()
```

Not sure, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: forgot to close `target` so the changes made in inside that streambuffer hasnt been stored to disk when you open another streambuffer pointing to the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not write to files instantly, instead holding them in a file buffer. The behaviour from Python 2 continues in Python 3, where calling the `flush` function on the file handle will cause it to write to the file (as per [this Python 2.6 question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18984092/9197650))

Making this change should result in the behaviour you want:

```
target.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3 + "\n")
target.flush()
```

Comment: Its not just a `Python` "problem". As far I know, this is how OS works against the filesystem. But you are right, if you want to trigger a write before / without having a `close()` you can use a `flush`

Answer (score 1):

open and read make after the target.close(). Because once you open with target you have to close it before opens with another object.

```
print("I'm going to write these to the file")
target.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3 + "\n")
target.close()
a=input("Please type the filename once again:")
b=open(a)
c=b.read()
print(c)
print("And finally, we close it.")
```

try this one :)

Comment: Just want to point out that flush() will trigger the same write to filesystem.