# Is there a way I could make my program save something that is being appended so even if the program is started its always in the list?

Tags: python-2.x

I would like to have my program store something in a list, and no matter what always have it in that list whether the program is restarted and so on.

Ive already tried the .add function, but I cant have .add on a list.

```
useradd_list = []

UserQuoteAdd_str in addquote_list:
        UserQuoteAdd_str = raw_input("What is your quote?")
        useradd_list.append(UserQuoteAdd_str)
```

What I need is a function that will save whatever the user types in memory and even if the program restarts, the list still has what the user typed.

Comment: Think about files. You are still on Python 2 which will not help you some months down the line.

Comment: that doesnt help me but thanks?

Comment: What you're looking for is called [persistence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html). It involves storing the data in a file to the hard disk in some way or another. In the link you will find various standard resources on how to mantain state across runs.

Comment: You can read an example of writing to files in Python 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984092/python-2-7-write-to-file-instantly). As your program's running memory is de-allocated upon termination, you'll need some other sort of resource (file, database, etc) to persist your data in, as @Anakhand is referencing.