# How to write txt files inside a infinite loop?

Tags: python, file

I am trying to make a loop that writes in a text file the date each time en event happens. but i can't get it to work since i need an infinite loop to run the program. If i put myfile.close() inside the loop even inside the "if x[14]=="track":" i get:

```
myfile.write(wri)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

However if i place it outside the loop the file Doesn't close and nothing is written in the output file.

Here is the code

```
while 1 :
    print("yes")
    response = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing', headers=headers)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    x=re.findall('"([^"]*)"', str(soup2)) 

    if isinstance(x, list)==True:
        if len(x)>=15:
            print(x[14])


            if x[14]=="track":


                os.system("TASKKILL /IM spotify.exe")
                sleep(2)
                subprocess.Popen("C:/Users/nebbu/AppData/Roaming/Spotify/Spotify.exe")
                sleep(2)
                import pyautogui
                pyautogui.press("playpause")
                pyautogui.press("l")
                print(x)
                wri=str(date)+"- -"+str(x[13]+": "+str(x[14]))
                myfile.write(wri)


myfile.close()
```

The loop never ends, i don't know if it has to end to close the file or if there is another way of doing it.

Comment: You can call `flush()` on a file to write out the buffer without closing the file.

Comment: For safely closing the file, you need a `try: ... finally: myfile.close()` block which will close the file no matter what. This can also be accomplished putting your code in a `with open(..., 'w') as myfile: ...` block. But yes, `flush` to write instantly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7 : Write to file instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984092/python-2-7-write-to-file-instantly)

Comment: Or you could not hold the file open the whole time and just open it in append mode when you want to write to it, then close it again.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make a custom function and call it for every time you want to add a new line to your text file. For example:

```
def f(dump):
    file = open('myfile.txt', 'a')
    file.write(dump)
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()
```

and then pass it the values you want to write on the fly.

Comment: Using `with` would be less error prone, e.g. `with open(‘myfile.txt’, ‘a’) as file: file.write(dump); file.write(‘\n’)` This is probably small enough to not need a separate function - but this is a matter of choice.